# Calling multiple methods on a CSV object

Tags: ruby, csv

I have constructed an Event Manager class that performs parsing actions on a CSV file, and produces html letters using erb. It is part of a jumpstart labs [tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/eventmanager.html#iteration-0%3a-loading-a-file)

The program works fine, but I am unable to call multiple methods on an object without the earlier methods interfering with the later methods. As a result, I have opted to create multiple objects to call instance methods on, which seems like a clunky inelegant solution. Is there a better way to do this, where I can create a single new object and call methods on it?

Like so:

```
eventmg = EventManager.new("event_attendees.csv")

eventmg.print_valid_phone_numbers

eventmg_2 = EventManager.new("event_attendees.csv")

eventmg_2.print_zipcodes

eventmg_3 = EventManager.new("event_attendees.csv")

eventmg_3.time_targeter

eventmg_4 = EventManager.new("event_attendees.csv")

eventmg_4.day_of_week

eventmg_5 = EventManager.new("event_attendees.csv")

eventmg_5.create_thank_you_letters
```

The complete code is as follows

```
    require 'csv'
    require 'sunlight/congress'
    require 'erb'

    class EventManager

      INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER = "0000000000"

    Sunlight::Congress.api_key = "e179a6973728c4dd3fb1204283aaccb5"

    def initialize(file_name, list_selections = [])
     puts "EventManager Initialized."

     @file = CSV.open(file_name, {:headers => true, 
       :header_converters => :symbol} )

     @list_selections = list_selections
    end

    def clean_zipcode(zipcode)
      zipcode.to_s.rjust(5,"0")[0..4]
    end

    def print_zipcodes
       puts "Valid Participant Zipcodes"
      @file.each do |line|
        zipcode = clean_zipcode(line[:zipcode])
        puts zipcode
      end
    end

    def clean_phone(phone_number)
      converted = phone_number.scan(/\d/).join('').split('')
      if converted.count == 10
        phone_number
      elsif phone_number.to_s.length < 10
    INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER 
      elsif phone_number.to_s.length == 11 && converted[0] == 1
        phone_number.shift
        phone_number.join('')
      elsif phone_number.to_s.length == 11 && converted[0] != 1
    INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER
    else 
      phone_number.to_s.length > 11
      INVALID_PHONE_NUMBER
    end
    end

    def print_valid_phone_numbers
      puts "Valid Participant Phone Numbers"
    @file.each do |line|
    clean_number = clean_phone(line[:homephone])
    puts clean_number
    end
    end

    def time_targeter
      busy_times = Array.new(24) {0}
      @file.each do |line|
        registration = line[:regdate]
        prepped_time = DateTime.strptime(registration, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
        prepped_time = prepped_time.hour.to_i
        # inserts filtered hour into the array 'list_selections'
        @list_selections << prepped_time
      end
      # tallies number of registrations for each hour
      i = 0
      while i < @list_selections.count
        busy_times[@list_selections[i]] += 1
        i+=1
      end
      # delivers a result showing the hour and the number of registrations
      puts "Number of Registered Participants by Hour:"
      busy_times.each_with_index {|counter, hours| puts "#{hours}\t#{counter}"}
    end


    def day_of_week
      busy_day = Array.new(7) {0}
      d_of_w = ["Monday:", "Tuesday:", "Wednesday:", "Thursday:", "Friday:", "Saturday:",         "Sunday:"]
      @file.each do |line|
        registration = line[:regdate]
        # you have to reformat date because of parser format
        prepped_date = Date.strptime(registration, "%m/%d/%y")
        prepped_date = prepped_date.wday
        # adds filtered day of week into array 'list selections'
        @list_selections << prepped_date  
      end
      i = 0
      while i < @list_selections.count
        # i is minus one since days of week begin at '1' and arrays begin at '0'
        busy_day[@list_selections[i-1]] += 1
        i+=1
      end
      #busy_day.each_with_index {|counter, day| puts "#{day}\t#{counter}"}
      prepared = d_of_w.zip(busy_day)
      puts "Number of Registered Participants by Day of Week"
      prepared.each{|date| puts date.join(" ")}
    end


    def legislators_by_zipcode(zipcode)
      Sunlight::Congress::Legislator.by_zipcode(zipcode)
    end


    def save_thank_you_letters(id,form_letter)
      Dir.mkdir("output") unless Dir.exists?("output")

      filename = "output/thanks_#{id}.html"

      File.open(filename,'w') do |file|
        file.puts form_letter
      end
    end


    def create_thank_you_letters
      puts "Thank You Letters Available in Output Folder"
      template_letter = File.read "form_letter.erb"
      erb_template = ERB.new template_letter

    @file.each do |line|
    id = line[0]
    name = line[:first_name]
    zipcode = clean_zipcode(line[:zipcode])
    legislators = legislators_by_zipcode(zipcode)

    form_letter = erb_template.result(binding)

    save_thank_you_letters(id,form_letter)
    end
    end

    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're experiencing this problem is because when you apply `each` to the result of `CSV.open` you're moving the file pointer each time. When you get to the end of the file with one of your methods, there is nothing for anyone else to read.

An alternative is to read the contents of the file into an instance variable at initialization with `readlines`. You'll get an array of arrays which you can operate on with `each` just as easily.

Comment: You totally nailed it. A simple change to CSV.read was all it took. Additionally, I needed to reset the array 'list_selections' via list_selections = [], in order to reuse it in multiple consecutive methods. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> "Is there a better way to do this, where I can create a single new object and call methods on it?"

Probably. If your methods are interfering with one another, it means you're changing state within the manager, instead of working on local variables.

Sometimes, it's the right thing to do (e.g. `Array#<<`); sometimes not (e.g. `Fixnum#+`)... Seeing your method names, it probably isn't.

Nail the offenders down and adjust the code accordingly. (I only scanned your code, but those `Array#<<` calls on an instance variable, in particular, look fishy.)